# A math contest question related to Ramsey numbers

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, ramsey-theory

In a group of 17 nations, any two nations are either mutual friends,
mutual enemies, or neutral to each other. Show that there is a
subgroup of 3 or more nations such that any two nations in the
subgroup share the same kind of relationship.

I am kind of guessing that you will have to use pigeonhole principle but not quite know how to apply?  Help will be appreciated.

---

The problem comes from [Fermat II 2014](http://www.math.utk.edu/MathContest/fermat/fermat2_2014.pdf), a [math contest](http://www.math.utk.edu/MathContest/) of the University of Tennessee for high school students.

Comment: You may have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory Your question really is: given a complete graph with 17 vertices, and given that each edge has a color (among three possible colors), show that there is a monochrome complete subgraph with 3 vertices. You can start with 2 colors and 6 vertices instead of 17, to see how it works.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, Thanks, I will look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will indeed use the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle): *if $n = km + 1$ objects are distributed among $m$ boxes, then the pigeonhole principle asserts that one of the box will contain at least $k + 1$ objects*.

To expand a bit about my comment, you can even actually *use* the result for $6$ vertices an $2$ colors, to solve for $17$ vertices and $3$ colors.

**The simpler case: $6$ vertices, $2$ colors**

Draw an hexagon, and consider a vertex $A$, and all $5$ diagonals that go to the other vertices. 
Among these $5$ diagonals, $3$ are of the same color, say red (pigeonhole principle).
They go to $B$, $C$ and $D$.

Now, if one of $BC$, $BD$ or $CD$ is red, then you have a monochrome triangle (complete with $A$).

Otherwise, they are all of the other color. But then $BCD$ is monochrome.

**17 vertices, 3 colors**

Same method.

Consider a vertex $A$, and the $16$ diagonals from it. Then at least $6$ have the same color: pigeonhole principle, again, with $3\times5+1$ objects (diagonals) in $3$ boxes (colors).

These $6$ diagonals, say red, go to $B,C,D,E,F,G$. Now if one of the edges of $BCDEFG$ if red, you complete the monochrome triangle with $A$.

Otherwise, they are all of the other two colors. But then this is an hexagon with two colors. Already solved above: there is a monochrome triangle in it.

---

I guess you can now solve the case of $66$ vertices and $4$ colors, and more generally, for $n$ colors, you may consider $u_n$ vertices, with

$$\begin{align}
u_n &=n(u_{n-1}-1)+2 \\
u_1 &=3
\end{align}$$

Then, in a complete graph with $u_n$ vertices and $n$ colors, you can find a monochrome triangle. That does not necessarily mean $u_n$ is the least number of vertices to achieve this, but it's an upper bound. The minimal numbers of vertices are [Ramsey numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamseyNumber.html).

You get for successive $u_n$: $3, 6, 17, 66, 327, 1958, 13701, 109602, 986411, 9864102\dots$ For example, a complete graph with $9864102$ vertices and $10$ colors has a monochrome triangle.

This is sequence [A073591](http://oeis.org/A073591) in OEIS.

You have also

$$u_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$$

The proof is easy by induction with

$$u_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n(n-1)!}{k!}+1=n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{k!}+1-1\right)+2=n(u_{n-1}-1)+2$$
It's also equal to $\lceil n! e\rceil$, where $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the [ceiling function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions), and $e=2.718\dots$